# createSQLQuery in hibernate uses Prepared Statement?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate

I'm using `createSQLQuery` with `setString` (No hard coded value) in Hibernate. I want to know that is Hibernate uses `PreparedStatement` for `createSQLQuery`?

**Concern:**

I want to preserve the execution plan created by this query in cache so next time same query fired on database, It would use same execution plan.

**FYI:** I'm using MSSQL Server 2008

```
/* This is just example I'm not using same query */
Query nativeSQLQuery = session.createSQLQuery("select Firstname from user_master where user_name = :param");
nativeSQLQuery.setString("param", "vicky.thakor");
```

I couldn't find stackoverflow link or even in google so please provide me link if any.

Comment: Use nativeSQLQuery everytime you want to execute queries. Just set parameters before executing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455717/does-hibernate-uses-jdbc-internally-or-jta-internally-or-it-is-confihurable

Comment: @Darshan Lila Make some sense in your answer. Your answer doesn't lead anywhere...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have tried to execute a query using Hibernates' createSQLQuery method then it will give me exception as below :-

```
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2275)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
```

From the above exception we can see that it will try to execute **com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2275)** internally.

I have also found a question by @Alex Serna at [Hibernate createSQLQuery parameter substitution](http://www.coderanch.com/t/562510/ORM/databases/Hibernate-createSQLQuery-parameter-substitution) where Alex also get the exception while trying to substitute table name.

Observing stack trace I think **Hibernate uses PreparedStatement for createSQLQuery internally**.

Comment: Its one of the weird way to answer the question but I like the way... I found another way that proves hibernate uses PreparedStatement. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Execute `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO` at SQL Server then execute any `select` query in hibernate and after that execute `SELECT usecounts, size_in_bytes, cacheobjtype, text
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle)
WHERE cacheobjtype != 'Parse Tree'` in SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate SQLQuery bypasses the Hibernate Session cache and queries ONLY against the database. You can read more @ [Hibernate: SQL vs HQL with the Session Cache](http://i-proving.com/2006/08/29/sql-vs-hql-with-the-session-cache/).